# Best way to define subpredicates with predicateEditor from users' perspective

Tags: xcode, nspredicateeditor

I am wondering how to use NSPredicateEditor to define subpredicates from out the user's perspective - and how to implement it.

Suppose we have a simple NSPredicateEditor created in IB as shown below.

[image]

It has 2 items to choose from:

- lastname
- address.street

So we can create a predicate  like

```
lastname ==[c] "Smith" OR lastname ==[c] "Miller" OR address.street ==[c] "3rd Avenue"
```

Now, if I want to have only Millers selected, living in the 3rd Avenue, what can I do ? I would prefer to have a button like "s" to create a subpredicate just below the selected line (Miller) to get this result:

[image]

```
  lastname ==[c] "Smith" OR (lastname ==[c] "Miller" AND address.street ==[c] "3rd Avenue")
```

Unfortunately, there is no other button than + or - for each item  (row).
Is there any other way ? Can it be done with low programmatically effort ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set "Nesting" of the predicate editor to "Compound". At runtime: Press the Option Key and the + button will change to … for adding a compound row.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Willeke. Option key works perfect for me ! Things can be simple if you know how ...